# Running python and c++ simultaneously and codependently on a Raspberry or a beagleboard

Tags: python, c++, http, raspberry-pi, uart

I have an architecture problem. I am developing a solution to access data from wireless sensors through an HTTP interface. 
Now, I am running a beaglebone with a nordic dongle which communicates via bluetooth with the sensors and sends the data through a UART link to the beagleboard on the one side. This code is written in C++.
On the other side, I have a code which runs the board as a server and communicates the data to the HTTP machine through the web link. The user get the data from the sensors in their web-browser. This code is written in Python.
Now..I need to link the two. What I have been looking for so far is wrapping the c++ functions in Python. This would work but the  code I have on c++ has a lot of functionality and I do not need all of them in the HTTP serving while a college of mine might do for his automation application. So we prefer to keep the c++ and python both running in the beagleboard server !!! (not sure if this is possible and this is my first questions)
If running python and c++ in such a machine is possible, my second idea is to store the data accessed from the UART through c++ in a random access memory location in the beagleboard untill python fetches this data and transmit it through the HTTP interface. and the possibility of this approach is my second question.
My third question is if anybody have a better idea on how to provide c++ and python interfacing in a beagleboard while both are running.

PS. it would also be alright  is we get rid of the palm devices and run the architecture in a normal linux machine.

Warm Regards from Snowy Austria
Raiyan

Comment: The problem description is a bit confusing.  It sounds like c++ code on a beaglebone uses bluetooth gather sensor data and sends that data via a serial port (UART) to a beagleboard.  The beagleboard then runs a Python web server.  And you want to know haw the web server can get the data from the serial port and display it on a web page.  Is that correct?

Comment: RootTwo A bluetooth device connected to the serial port uses c to gather data from sensors. then communicates it to beagleboard through UART. beagleboard runs both c++ and python. C++ for processing sensor data (real time capability that is why its preferred to python here) and python to run an http server in case a user would like to gather data from HTTP link.

Comment: There are many ways to tackle this problem. If the sensor data update rate and volume is not unreasonable, you might try having your sensor code (c++) send and http POST request to the webserver (python).  The body of the post would contain the data in an easy to parse format (tab separated values, json; etc.).  You could send the data when it changes, or at a fixed rate (every .1 secs, or something)--send all the data every time, or just data that changed.  I haven't used it yet, but C++ Requests looks like an easy http client library [https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr].